# $R$ relation $R$ defined on $xRy \iff 3x+2y$ is divisible by $5$. I need to show that $R$ is an equivalence relation.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-set-theory, equivalence-relations

I have proven that $R$ is reflexive and transitive. But I am stuck on proving that $R$ is symmetric.

I know that, we must show that it $xRy$ then $yRx$.

I did:
$xRy \Rightarrow 3y + 2y = 5k$.

*How do I go from here to prove $yRx$, this is where I'm suck*

Comment: You should say that $R$ is a relation on $\mathbb{Z}$ or $\mathbb{N}$.

Comment: Be sure to convert math equations to [mathjax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) next time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: $3y+2x=(5x+5y)-(3x+2y)$.

Comment: I tried this and it does get me to the conclusion that R is symmetric, But I do not understand where this came from. Could you please explain why you did that? Thanks

Comment: Trying to find a connection between $3x+2y$ and $3y+2x$ which somehow involves multiples of $5$.

Comment: Have you studied congruence (modular) arithmetic?  If so, you should be able to re-express the relation between $x$ and $y$ in a very easy way.